compileSdk and targetSdkVersion issue with Android Flavors
I had compileSdk and targetSdkVersion set to API 34 and used TypedValue.deriveDimension, which has been introduced with API 34.
Now I had to switch to Flavors - one uses SDK 33 and one SDK 34.
But even when compiling the Flavor for SDK 34, it doesn't know TypedValue.deriveDimension anymore.
I would have expected, that the code still compiles when having compileSdk and targetSdkVersion set to API 34 with a flavor.
Any ideas why and how to solve this?
